# Magento: How can i assign a block to a parent block added to a CMS page

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system, block, magento-1.6

I hope you can understand my question!!

The question below is to do with assigning and referencing blocks within a Magento CMS Page.

### The Problem

I have a cms page called Home page. The content of this page is

```
{{block type='core/template' name='homepage_html' template='page/html/homepage.phtml'}}
```

In page/html/homepage.phtml i have some basic html for my sites homepage.

**-> Up to this point everything works fine.**

I want to pull in my latest posts from my aw_blog module. I have a file aw_blog/homepage_posts.phtml that works perfectly if i add this code to cms.xml

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/blog" name="home_blog" template="aw_blog/homepage_posts.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

The trouble with this is it adds the posts under the content in my page/html/homepage.phtml file.

I have this line in my page/html/homepage.phtml where i would like the list of posts to appear

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home_blog') ?>
```

and have tried referencing homepage_html in place of content in my cms.xml file

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="homepage_html">
        <block type="blog/blog" name="home_blog" template="aw_blog/homepage_posts.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

but no joy!!!

### The Question

So my question to you is, is there a way to assign the latest post block to the homepage_html block in order to draw in the latest posts using the $this->getChildHtml() method.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just as a test, if you rename the second "home_blog" to "home_blog2" does it change anything?  Since I don't have your entire code, I am leaving open the possibility that "home_blog" may have been instantiated more than once for the <cms_index_index/> scope.  fwiw, I would have thought that your second example (placing the block under "homepage_html") would have been correct, but if you left the first example's home_blog instantiation, the two blocks' identical names would conflict with each other, which in my experience leads to neither being rendered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can confirm that the only xml within the <cms_index_index/> scope is the home_blog block being added to the homepage_html. I Still have not managed to get this to work, but i have found a alternate solution. I have created a CMS static block which call the homepage_posts.phtml and then called that static block in my homepage.phtml file with `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('latest-posts')->toHtml() ?>`. This works perfectly but im sure there must be a better solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to call your child in "page/html/homepage.phtm"l like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home_blog') ?>
```

Comment: You can see in my question i am already trying to call my child that way. My homepage.phtml file is just some div structure with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home_blog') ?> attempting to call my posts where i would like them to display
`